# flutter err : ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart, gradle

I'am trying to build apk via  flutter but every time i run the app i got this err

```
 Flutter Fix ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
           │ [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                                                                           │
           │ Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/gradle.html#plugin-and-versions, then update D:\Taxi\Flutter\Driver\android\build.gradle: │
           │ ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'                                                                                                          │
           └────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

The problem is i already use the latest version

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0-RC'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'    
    }
}
```

I also tried
`ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20`
but the same problem
I can't  handle the error

i need to find the problem source or if anyone have the solution

Answer (score 2):

Make sure about IDE support:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#ide-support

and use:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
```